# Meta-regression with two control variables

Tags: r, regression, metafor

I want to calculate meta regressions with the `meta` package. But the regression must be controlled for two variables `x` and `y`. Does anyone know how I can bring my control variable into the calculations?

`library(meta)`
`meta_regr <- metareg(meta_analysis, ~year)`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add covariates with formula notationn as you would with normal regression with `lm()` function and family.

```
library(meta) 
meta_regr <- metareg(meta_analysis, ~ year + x + y)
```